# Is it possible to change properties in Ember routes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What is the correct way to set properties on an Ember route?  I have a title message that I would like to be displayed on page load and then I would like to change that title as the user interacts with the page.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  title: "Welcome!",

  model(thing1) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      thing1: this.store.findRecord('thing1', thing1.thing_id),
      thing2: this.store.findAll('thing2'),
      thing3: this.store.findAll('thing3')
    });
  },

  actions: {
    changeTitle() {
      this.set("title", "I changed!")
    }
  }
});
```

In my template I load another component and pass in the value for title

```
{{title-tile title=title}}
```

And in my component title, I print out (theoretically) the title:

```
{{title}}
```

I have also tried removing the intermediary step and just printing out the title directly but that doesn't work.

In the console I have no errors, and I am otherwise able to print out the model data from the RSVP hash.  There is no (obvious) documentation on this.  All documentation focuses on printing out model properties.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

It appears to me that routes are just meant to handle models and that components are supposed to take care of everything else.

I've actually tried explicitly calling the title to be set on route load and it still doesn't work.

```
...
init() {
  title: "Welcome!"
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a computed property in hash passed to template:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  title: 'Welcome!',

  model(thing1) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      // ... omitted for brevity
      title: Ember.computed(() => this.get('title')) // computed property
    });
  },

  actions: {
    changeTitle() {
      this.set("title", "I changed!")
      this.refresh(); // it is required to refresh model
    }
  }
});
```

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/057cf35dd0651eb66646)
- [Full code behind demo.](http://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/057cf35dd0651eb66646)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. I'm still wrapping my head around the architecture of Ember.